# VSCode Insiders - how to stop showing ghost text suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On my VSCode editor, when ever I write something, this type of ghost texts appears
[image]

Does anyone know how to stop this from showing?

Comment: looks like an inline Emmet preview

Comment: Are you using the Insiders Build?  If so, try disabling `Emmet: Use Inline Completions`.